# Using config split to keep dev modules separate: how to manage enabled/disabled states?

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm using [the config split documentation to exclude dev module configuration on my site.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/configuration-split/creating-a-simple-split-configuration-dev-modules-only-in-dev)

I made a configuration split that blacklists the following modules:

- Devel
- Kint
- Field UI
- Menu UI
- Views UI

I then edited `settings.php` so that this config split is active on my dev environment but not my test or prod environments:

```
  elseif ($_ENV['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'dev') {
    // Enable dev modules.
    $config['config_split.config_split.dev']['status'] = TRUE;
```

In the UI (`/admin/config/development/configuration/config-split`), the **Status** of the config split on the dev env is **active (overwritten)**.

However, when I close the database from live and run `drush cim` on dev, the dev modules are not installed,

I am guessing this is because `config/core.extension` has the dev modules disabled.  However, I want them disabled in this file because if they are enabled, the modules will also be enabled on production.  So what am I supposed to do to get the dev modules imported on dev?

If I log in as an administrator and change the config split to TRUE in the UI, then run `drush cim`, the dev modules will be enabled.  However, when I run `drush cim` again, the dev modules will be uninstalled again, so this doesn't work, either.

The documentation says: `These settings need a cache clear when overridden in settings.php and the split needs to be single imported before the config import for new values to take effect.`

I did the cache clear, but I don't know how to single import the config with Drush.